# Definition of a recursive ordinal

Tags: definition, examples-counterexamples, computability, ordinals

I'm having trouble understanding the definition of reclusive or computable ordinal - Wikipedia defines it as follows:

"...an ordinal $\alpha$ is said to be recursive if there is a recursive well-ordering of a subset of the natural numbers having the order type $\alpha$."

I find this hard to picture. Is there a different way of explaining it, or some examples?

Answer (score 1):

Think in "recursive..." as explicit. Example: let be $R$ the relation in $\omega$ defined by
$$\forall n>0:\ n\,R\,0,$$
$$\forall m,n>0:\ n\,R\,m\iff n<m.$$
The order type of $(\omega,R)$ is $\omega+1$.
Another example: by an explicit bijection $\omega\longrightarrow\omega\times\omega$ you can define in $\omega$ an order of type $\omega^2$.

Comment: Another example: consider the ordering given by $a<b$ if $a$ is odd and $b$ is even, OR $a$ and $b$ are both odd and $a<b$, OR $a$ and $b$ are both even and $a<b$. This has order type $\omega+\omega$ - it looks like $1<3<5<7< . . . <0<2<4<6<8<. . . $.